# Unable to create directory or file in WebHdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

Hortonworks Sandbox file browser shows WebHdfsException, and in CLI I'm unable to create directory or file. What is wrong?

```
WebHdfsException at /filebrowser/

<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/filebrowser/
Django Version:     1.2.3
Exception Type:     WebHdfsException
Exception Value:    

<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Exception Location:

```
/usr/lib/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py in _stats, line 209
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.6
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    ['', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.6.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/BabelDjango-0.2.2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.7.2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Markdown-2.0.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.9.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Paste-1.7.2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyYAML-3.09-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pygments-1.3.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Spawning-0.9.6-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.5.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/configobj-4.6.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap-1.0.7-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_extensions-0.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_nose-0.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/elementtree-1.2.6_20050316-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/enum-0.4.4-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/eventlet-0.9.14-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/greenlet-0.3.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/happybase-0.6-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kerberos-1.1.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lockfile-0.8-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.2.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/moxy-1.0.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pam-0.1.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysqlite-2.5.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_daemon-1.5.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.13-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytidylib-0.2.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sasl-0.1.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sh-1.08-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson-2.0.9-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/threadframe-0.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/thrift-0.9.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib2_kerberos-0.1.6-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xlrd-0.9.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src', '/usr/lib/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src', '/usr/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/about/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/filebrowser/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/hcatalog/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/help/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/jobsub/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/pig/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/proxy/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/shell/src', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/useradmin/src', '/usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin', '/usr/lib64/python2.6', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/gen-py', '/usr/lib/hue', '/usr/lib64/python26.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../gen-py', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/../../gen-py', '/usr/lib/hue/apps/proxy/src/proxy/../../gen-py']
Server time:    Sun, 31 May 2015 22:05:23 -0700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try by reimporting the sandbox again..I solved the issue by deleting and reimporting it again to VM.

Answer (score 0):

When you import sanbox, please verify it imported successfully. When you start your sandbox, make sure that all services are started there should not be any error during start.Type `ifconfig` in terminal. You will get a `IP` address starting with `192.168.XX.XXX`. Replace `127.0.0.1` with that `IP` address. It should work.